# Tweaking an AppleScript to remove the prompt window

Tags: applescript

Hello and thanks for your help, I have file names sharing the same tiles, like 1_Title1_a, 2_Title1_b, etc, and I got this script that will create a folder with the name of each titles found in a folder, like it will create a folder named Title1, a folder named Title2, etc. The thing is, this script opens with a pop up window asking me where my big folder with all my files is, I would like to bypass this pop up window because the files will always be in the same folder, let's say /Users/Documents/Here. I couldn't tweak the script to do that....May I ask for some help? In the first line, "Choose folder" should just be my folder path /Users/Documents/Here. Thanks

```
set chosenFolder to (Choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to set fileList to files of chosenFolder

set TID to text item delimiters
set text item delimiters to "_"
repeat with aFile in fileList
    set fileName to name of aFile
    set textItems to text items of fileName
    if (count textItems) = 1 then
        set fileExtension to name extension of aFile
        set folderName to text 1 thru ((get offset of "." & fileExtension in fileName) - 1) of fileName
    else
        set folderName to first item of textItems
    end if
    set sourceFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (aFile as text)
    set destinationFile to quoted form of (POSIX path of chosenFolder & folderName & "/" & fileName)
    do shell script "ditto " & sourceFile & space & destinationFile
    do shell script "rm " & sourceFile
end repeat
set text item delimiters to TID
```

Comment: This needs more than a tweak.  It's clear you're trying to move files into similarly named folders, but this could be done more effectively.  But, to answer your immediate question: `set chosenFolder to the alias POSIX file named "/path/to/folder"`

Comment: @CJK Thank you so much this works great!!!